# Finding largest contour - OpenCV - Java

Tags: java, opencv, contour, corner-detection

I am trying to find the largest countour in an image after performing some per-processing steps such as: 
1) GrayScale
2) Threshold - binarization
3) Canny

Then code for finding contour:
     List contours = new ArrayList();

```
        Imgproc.findContours(img_gray, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        double maxArea = -1;
        int maxAreaIdx = -1;
        MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
        MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        MatOfPoint largest_contour = contours.get(0);
        //largest_contour.ge
        List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        //Imgproc.drawContours(imgSource,contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);

        for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
            temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
            //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
            if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                //check if this contour is a square
                MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
                int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
                MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
                Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize*0.05, true);
                if (approxCurve_temp.total() == 4) {
                    maxArea = contourarea;
                    maxAreaIdx = idx;
                    approxCurve=approxCurve_temp;
                    largest_contour = temp_contour;
                }
            }
        }

       Imgproc.cvtColor(img_gray, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
       Mat sourceImage =Highgui.imread(filePath + filename);
       double[] temp_double;
       temp_double = approxCurve.get(0,0);       
       Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

       //Core.circle(imgSource,p1,55,new Scalar(0,0,255));
       //Imgproc.warpAffine(sourceImage, dummy, rotImage,sourceImage.size());
       temp_double = approxCurve.get(1,0);       
       Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);           

      // Core.circle(imgSource,p2,150,new Scalar(255,255,255));
       temp_double = approxCurve.get(2,0);       
       Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
       //Core.circle(imgSource,p3,200,new Scalar(255,0,0));
       temp_double = approxCurve.get(3,0);       
       Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);
      // Core.circle(imgSource,p4,100,new Scalar(0,0,255));
```

As you can see that I am trying to get the four corner points namely, P1, P2, P3, P4.

The issue is that I am not getting the correct points when I click an image from my phone camera but it works well when I take an image from the internet.

For example, I take the below given image from my phone:
[image: Camera Image]

The corner points detected are:

```
p1 = 1485.0-922.0
p2 = 1469.0-922.0
p3 = 1485.0-906.0
p4 = 1469.0-906.0
```

Which is disgusting. How can the x-y value be same for 2 points.

perspective transform from these points:
[image: Perspective transform]

When I take an image from internet all the points are calculated with perfection.

Its clearly something from the background.

Can someone help me to sort this out?

Comment: Could you show us where those points are on the image?

Comment: You may want to user another photo, unless you are the person the card.

Comment: My aim was to get the points and then do perspective transform to get only the card from the image. So in this case, the perspective transform is giving me the background image. I have updated it above.

Comment: @Anubian - could you show me how can I mark those points in the code given above?

Comment: Had a similar issue. It is due to the poor image quality. Use the original image